# Replace text of multiple nodes at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build an online version of my resume and I would like the names of the months in my work experience to shrink based on the size of the screen, e.g. have it go from January 2011 - January 2012 to Jan 2011 - Jan 2012.

Here is a sample of my HTML

```
<section id="work">
  <div id="job1">
    <ul> 
      <li>September 2013 - Present</li>
      <li>Job Title</li>
      <li>Employer Name</li>
      <li>Location</li>
    </ul>               
    <ul>
      <li>job duties</li>
      <li>job duties</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>    
  <div id="job2">
    <ul> 
      <li>January 2012 - September 2013</li>
      <li>Job Title</li>
      <li>Employer Name</li>
      <li>Location</li>
    </ul>             
    <ul>
      <li>job duties</li>
      <li>job duties</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</section>
```

I initially did this by shortening each text node one-by-one, like so:

```
function shrinkMonths(idName) {
        var dates = $(idName).find("ul:first-child li:first-child");
        var words = dates.text().split(" ");
        words[0] = words[0].substr(0,3);
        if (idName !== "#job1") {
            words[3] = words[3].substr(0,3);    
        }
        return words.join(" ");
    }

$("#job1").find("ul:first-child li:first-child").text(shrinkMonths("#job1"));
$("#job2").find("ul:first-child li:first-child").text(shrinkMonths("#job2"));
```

You can see this at http://codepen.io/polly_nomial/pen/nghJx

I would like to do this all at once so I selected all of my dates at once, and this created a string of all my dates but the year of last date was concatenated with the first month of the next date (September, 2013, -, PresentJanuary, 2012, -, September, 2013NextMonth). So I was able to split the text appropriately and shorten the months, but when I try to return the text, it gives back the entire string to each node instead of individually.

```
function shrinkMonths(list) {
  var words = list.split(" ");
  var temp1 = null;
  var temp2 = null;

  for(var i = 0; (4*i+3)+i < words.length; i++) {
    if(i === 0) {
      temp1 = words[4*i+3].slice(0,7);
      temp2 = words[4*i+3].slice(7);
      words.splice(4*i+3,1,temp1,temp2);
    }
    else {
      temp1 = words[(4*i+3) + i].slice(0,4);
      temp2 = words[(4*i+3) + i].slice(4);
      words.splice((4*i+3) + i,1,temp1,temp2);
    }
  }

  words[0] = words[0].slice(0,3);

  var k = 1;
  while(5*k+2 < words.length) {
    words[5*k - 1] = words[5*k - 1].slice(0,3);
    words[5*k + 2] = words[5*k + 2].slice(0,3);
    k++;
  }  

  return words.join(" ");
}

var change = shrinkMonths($(".work").find("div ul:first-child li:first-child").text());

$(".work").find("div ul:first-child li:first-child").text(change);
```

You can see this here http://codepen.io/polly_nomial/pen/Jorgn

So how do I select all the text nodes at once, change them, and then return each text node individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate across the dates, not jam all their data together and then split it out:

```
    dates.each(function() {
       var date = $(this);
       var text = date.text();
       ...
       date.text(changedText);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

CSS only idea. What if instead of plain month name `September` you use something like this:

```
<span class="month" data-full="September" data-short="Sep"></span>
```

Then using media queries you can do this:

```
.month:after {
    content: attr(data-full);
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .month:after {
        content: attr(data-short);
    }
}
```

Here we go. No Javascript involved. 7 lines of code. IE9+ (media queries), IE8+ (`:after`).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ryAb3/

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach a lot